# Using CGPathContainsPoint on CAShapeLayer.path After Moving the Layer

Tags: objective-c, cgpath, cashapelayer

When using CGPathContainsPoint my results are consistent with the original position of the CAShapeLayer but not its current position.  Is this normal, and do I need to apply the tranformation on the CGPoint I am testing, or should I be looking for a problem elsewhere in my code?  My CAShapeLayer was simply moved by updating its .position property one time.

For completeness, I'm adding that my CAShapeLayer is a sublayer of a UIButton.layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, I needed to convert the touch point's location (which is in the UIButton's coordinate space) to the CAShapLayer's coordinate space using:

```
CGPoint convertedTouchPoint = [myButton.layer convertPoint:touchPoint toLayer:myShapeLayer];
```

Comment: save me 8 years later)